# for loop with eventhandler

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementbyid

I need add an Event Handler to the li element and then console.log() the name of the shirt they selected. 
I am getting a typeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value. I am new to this and am struggling to figure this out.

```
  <h3>Shirts</h3>
    <ul id='list'>
     <li>Biker Jacket</li>
     <li>Mens Shirt</li>
    </ul>


var lis = document.getElementById("list").getElementByTagName('li'); 
  for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i ++){
    lis[i].onclick = (event) => {

  }
    console.log(event); 

  }
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `getElementByTagName`. Why not use `querySelectorAll` instead? `const lis = document.querySelectorAll('#list > li');`

Comment: Also your `console.log()` is outside your click handler block

Comment: Actually there is `getElementsByTagName`, focus on `Elements`. But as you said `querySelector[flavor] is more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use children instead of getElementByTagName and loop over it with the use of **Array.from**, it's es6 syntax. **Array.from** will not work in es5.

```
var lis = Array.from(document.getElementById("list").children);

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i ++){
    lis[i].onclick = (event) => {

    }
    console.log(event); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding event listeners to each li is not good as if there are a lot, you will end up having a lot of handlers. You can use event delegation to solve the issue. Every event that happens on an element propagates upward to it's parent to Grand parents and so on. So you can add just one event listener on ul and detect which on which li the click happened and do the processing like wise. Here is an example:

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // e.target is the clicked element!
    // If it was a list item
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        // List item found!  Output the ID!
        console.log("List item ", e.target.id.replace("post-", ""), " was clicked!");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the list item then add a click event and `innerText` to get the shirt.

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('#list > li');
lis.forEach(function(list){
 list.onclick = () => {
  console.log(list.innerText)
 }; 
})
```

```html
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
  <li>Biker Jacket</li>
  <li>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```